# I can't save files in /var/www/html

Tags: centos, permissions, php, apache-httpd

I'm running CentOS 6.5 and I'm having problems saving my files to `/var/www/html`.

The folder currently belongs to `root` and I have gone through everything from SELinux to configuration procedures, but I hardly understand those procedures.

I believe the permission restriction is also preventing me from viewing my local web pages in the web browser. I want to be able to move files to and from the `/var/www/html` folder without restrictions.

Comment: Log in as root, and `touch /var/www/html/test.html` and see what happens. `Permission denied` or something else?

Comment: @Kis: If this issue resolved then please select the answer that resolved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If the folder and files are owned by root, you would do well to assign them to another user. Assuming that your username is `kis` and that your webserver user runs in the group `apache2`, run the following as root:

```
# chown -R kis:apache2 /var/www/
```

Additionally, set the directories as permissions `755` and the files as `644`:

```
$ cd /var/www/
$ find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
$ find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Note that terminal commands show the bash prompt: `#` or `$`. The Bash prompt `#` means that the command is to be run as root, and the Bash prompt `$` means that the command is to be run as a regular user.

Comment: @Nate the touch command creates the file when I log in as root. However, I was discouraged adamantly from logging in as root.

Comment: my group is root and the owner is root ... is it safe to still run that command @dotancohen

Comment: The first command you will _need_ to be root to run. I'll clarify that in the answer. The other two should be as your regular user.

Comment: Wow. thanks. That worked. However, i have no idea what I just did. Can you please direct me to a book or any place i can get to understand these things at a deeper level. Or at least a level with which i will know what I am doing. Otherwise, thank you very much

Comment: The answer as it stands says exactly what each command will do. The first will assign `/var/www` to another user, `cd` you probably know already, and the two `find` commands set the directories as permissions `755` and the files as permissions `644`.

Comment: @Kis: By the way, the quote in your user profile is terrific.